# splitting list in python by keyword

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list like the following:

```
lst = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'start', 'b', 'end', 'a', 'a','a','start','b','b','b','end','a','a','a','a','start','b','b','end']
```

and my desired result is to split the list into sublists like this:

```
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['start', 'b', 'end'], ['a', 'a','a'],['start','b','b','b','end'],['a','a','a','a'],['start','b','b','end']]
```

so start and end are keywords, is there anyway you can use .split() by using particular keywords/if it matches?

So far I have made a function which finds the indices of 'start' i.e. `starting_ind = [3, 9, 18]` and `ending_ind = [5, 13, 21]` however if I do

```
temp=[]
for i in range(len(starting_ind)):
       x = lst[starting_ind[i]: ending_ind[i]]
       temp += x
print(temp)
```

the result is incorrect.

Comment: In what *ways* is the result incorrect, and what have you tried to correct them?

Comment: Will the last element in `lst` always be `end`?

Comment: Not necessarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution doesn't require you to calculate indices beforehand:

```
lst = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'start', 'b', 'end', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'start', 'b', 'b',
       'b', 'end', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'start', 'b', 'b', 'end', 'a', 'a', 'a']
result = []
sublist = []

for el in range(len(lst)):
  if lst[el] == 'start':
    result.append(sublist.copy())
    sublist.clear()
    sublist.append(lst[el])
  else:
    sublist.append(lst[el])
    if lst[el] == 'end':
      result.append(sublist.copy())
      sublist.clear()
    if el == len(lst) - 1:
      result.append(sublist)
print(result)
```

The result is:

```
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['start', 'b', 'end'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['start', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'end'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['start', 'b', 'b', 'end'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
```

Comment: This is actually great, thank you so much. Just one question though if lst doesn't end in 'end' i.e. there was another 'a', 'a', 'a' on the end of lst then it doesn't seem to pick up on that

Comment: I've updated my answer so it correctly works for that case as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible way to use regular expression to extract the patterns, please check if it's acceptable:

```
import re

lst = ['a','a','a', 'start','b','end', 'a','a','a', 'start','b','b','b','end', 'a','a','a','a', 'start','b','b','end']
result = []
for e in re.findall('a_[a_]+|start[_b]+_end', '_'.join(lst)):
    result.append(e.strip('_').split('_'))
print(result)
```

Output is as desired:

```
[['a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['start', 'b', 'end'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['start', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'end'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['start', 'b', 'b', 'end']]
```

A better way is this:

```
result = []
for e in re.split(r'(start[_b]+_end)', '_'.join(lst)):
    result.append(e.strip('_').split('_'))
print([x for x in result if x != ['']])
```

Same output

Answer (score 0):

You can write so:

```
   lst = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'start', 'b', 'end',
          'a', 'a','a','start','b','b','b','end','a','a','a','a','start','b','b','end']
   temp=[]
   ind = [0, 3, 6, 9, 14, 18, 22]
   for i in range(len(ind)-1):
          x = lst[ind[i]: ind[i+1]]
          temp.append(x)
   print(temp)
```

and you will get:

```
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['start', 'b', 'end'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['start', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'end'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['start', 'b', 'b', 'end']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can be certain that your keywords will always appear in pairs, and in the right order (i.e. there will never be a `'start'` without an `'end'` that follows it, at some point in the list), this should work:

```py
l = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'start', 'b', 'end', 'a', 'a','a','start','b','b','b','end','a','a','a','a','start','b','b','end']

def get_sublist(l):
    try: 
        return l[:l.index('end') + 1] if l.index('start') == 0 else l[:l.index('start')]
    except ValueError:
        return l

result = []

while l:
    sublist = get_sublist(l)
    result.append(sublist)
    l = l[len(sublist):]

print(result)
```

Gives the following result:

```py
[['a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['start', 'b', 'end'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['start', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'end'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['start', 'b', 'b', 'end']]
```